# Как получить регулярное выражение, которое бы проверяло на корректность протокол и домен в URL-адресах?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Хотел задать регулярное выражение, которое бы проверяло на корректность протокол и домен в URL-адресах (пользователь должен иметь возможность вставлять как URL на главную, так и обычные ссылки).

Написал регулярное выражение

```
^https?:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.?[0-9a-zA-Z-]+?\.?[0-9a-zA-Z-]+?\.[a-zA-Z]+\/?.+
```

Выражение подразумевает, что если в урле более 4-х доменных уровней, он будет светить их как некорректные. Домен верхнего уровня должен состоять только из латиницы.

Протестировал на онлайн дебагерах (https://regex101.com/ , https://uvsoftium.ru/php/regexp.php).

Проблема в том, что ввиду малого опыта программирования не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы домен верхнего уровня мог состоять только из латиницы (без цифр). Данное выражение считает, что https://google.c0m/ и http://domain.ru?link являются корректными.

Интересно как решается этот момент. Прошу Вас подсказать как лучше поступить. Спасибо!

Comment: *ак сделать так, чтобы домен верхнего уровня мог состоять только из латиницы* Простите, вот что Вы сейчас назвали "домен первого уровня"?

Comment: Есть такой прекрасный TLD .рф. Например http://кто.рф

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www.){0,1}([0-9A-Za-z]+.)([A-Za-z]+)([\/\?&]|$)
```

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/HyBWY7/1)

---

Впрочем, `(www.){0,1}` всё же, наверное, лишнее, хватит и

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9A-Za-z]+.)([A-Za-z]+)([\/\?&]|$)
```

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/HyBWY7/2)

---

> domain/net подсвечивается как корректный (отсутствует домен верхнего уровня); dom3.dom2.ru - как некорректный (3 уровня);

Точно, просмотрел.

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)([A-Za-z]+)([\/\?&]|$)
```

[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/HyBWY7/3)

> domain.ru?link - как корректный

Это корректный адрес. Знак вопроса не входит в домен, это разделитель домена и параметров.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ответ! http://domain/net/ подсвечивается как корректный (отсутствует домен верхнего уровня);
http://dom3.dom2.ru/ - как некорректный (3 уровня);
http://domain.ru?link - как корректный (фактически в домене верхнего уровня присутствует запрещенный знак вопроса).

Comment: @psjkee Угу, просмотрел ляпсус. Поправил.

Comment: Сердечно благодарю за помощь! Решил всё-таки разделять часть протокол-домен от остального урл (обрезка строки до 3-го слеша), далее работал уже с этой частью по выражению /^(https|http):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]+\/?$)/. В случае, если этот слеш отсутствовал - считал, что ссылка ведёт на главную страницу.  Большое спасибо за ответы. Хорошего вечера!)

Comment: @psjkee *(обрезка строки до 3-го слеша)* На самом деле - до одного из `([/\?]|$)` (ну и теоретически `&`, а также, не исключаю, что ещё какие-то) после `//:` при наличии и с самого начала при отсутствии. Кстати, для упрощения протокол тоже можно отрезать (предварительно проверив, что это не `зюзюзю//:`).